# Is there another way of saying someone messed up your hair in a jokey matter?

Tags: synonyms

You like in the movies where there’s a guy who messes up a boy hair and say stuff like “you little rascal”?

Answer (score 1):

It's called ***ruffle***:

> **ruffle**
>   to touch or move something smooth so that it is not even:
>   *She affectionately ruffled his hair with her hand as she passed.*
>   *-- [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ruffle)*

> 'Can we try a bit now, Mum?' Duncan asked eagerly. He was thirteen, and his voice broke endearingly on 'now'. His mother eased the kink in her back and then ruffled his short brown hair. 'Later, pet, when it's cooled down and your dad's home.'
>   -- [*Looking After Your Own* by Evelyn Hood](https://books.google.com/books?id=aKEPAIcaMzYC&pg=PT8&dq=ruffled%20his%20hair&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjq8qmooIrgAhXRMewKHTfWD-8Q6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=ruffled%20his%20hair&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

to **muss**  [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/muss)

> make messy or untidy “the child mussed up my hair”

Muss means "make untidy," it's almost always used to talk about **hair**. The word muss has been around since the nineteenth century, and it was probably originally a variation on mess.